# Define you own global variable for JenkinsJob (Not for ALL jobs!!)

Tags: jenkins

I have ha Jenkins job that has a string input parameter of the build flags for the make command in my Jenkins job. My problem is that some users forget to change the parameter values when we have a release branch. So I want to overwrite the existing string input parameter (or create a new one) that should be used if the job is a release job.

This is the statement I want to add:

If branch "*release*" then ${params.build_flag} = 'DEBUGSKIP=TRUE'

and the code that is not working is:

```
pipeline {
agent none


parameters {
    string(name: 'build_flag', defaultValue: 'DEBUGSKIP=TRUE', description: 'Flags to pass to build')   

    If {
       allOf {
            branch "*release*"
            expression {
                ${params.build_flag} = 'DEBUGSKIP=TRUE'
            }
        }
    }else{
    ${params.build_flag} = 'DEBUGSKIP=FALSE'
    }
}
```

The code above explains what I want to do but I don't know to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, see if you could use the [JENKINS EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), with your pipeline, using [the supported use-case](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-JenkinsPipeline):

> Injection of EnvVars defined in the "`Properties Content`" field of the Job Property
>
> These EnvVars are being injected to the script environment and will be inaccessible via the "env" Pipeline global variable (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099017/6309))

Or writing the right values in a file, and using that file content as "`Properties Content`" of a downstream job (as [shown there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128636/6309)).